# Android, Change App:theme value of SwitchCompat programmatically

Tags: android, user-interface, switchcompat

I want to change the **app:theme** attribute's value of SwitchCompat to something else (@style/switchColorStyleBlue).  How can I do that programmatically? (app:theme basically changes the color of toggle)

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
android:id="@+id/switch"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:theme="@style/switchColorStylePink"/>
```

I have tried this code but its not showing appropriate results:

```
    SwitchCompat switchCompat = new SwitchCompat(this);
    switchCompat.setId(i);
    switchCompat.setSwitchTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), R.style.switchColorStylePink);
    switchCompat.setChecked(false);
    containerRelativeLayout.addView(switchCompat);
```

[image]

What I want is to change the theme (color of the switch) from pink to blue or whatever viceversa.

Comment: Have you tried the above code by running it? Because from the documentation in the developer website I seriously suspect is you can set the theme above given way as well. 

See the XML Attribute section below the Summary

Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SwitchCompat.html#setSwitchTypeface(android.graphics.Typeface,%20int)

Also please tell me what exactly you wish to accomplish in this SwitchCompat

Comment: Yes i've tried the above mentioned code in my question. And I've updated the question for more clarity. Meanwhile seeing the documentation.

Comment: Give me sometime. I am looking for a solution and will get back to you...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this... I have tested and it is working perfectly fine

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int[][] states = new int[][] {
            new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_checked},
            new int[] {android.R.attr.state_checked},
    };

    int[] thumbColors = new int[] {
            Color.BLACK,
            Color.RED,
    };

    int[] trackColors = new int[] {
            Color.GREEN,
            Color.BLUE,
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SwitchCompat switchCompat = (SwitchCompat) findViewById(R.id.switch);
        DrawableCompat.setTintList(DrawableCompat.wrap(switchCompat.getThumbDrawable()), new ColorStateList(states, thumbColors));
        DrawableCompat.setTintList(DrawableCompat.wrap(switchCompat.getTrackDrawable()), new ColorStateList(states, trackColors));
    }
}
```

---

You will only need to update the "trackColors" and the "thumbColor" as per you requirement/needs.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

You can try `switchCompat.setSwitchTypeface(typeface, R.style.switchColorStyleBlue);`

Ref:- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SwitchCompat.html#setSwitchTypeface(android.graphics.Typeface,%20int)

Comment: It only sets the typeface and style in which the "text" should be displayed on the switch.